# How to set the href in a DataTables button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables-1.10

I use DataTables to format my tables. I also use their plugins for Buttons. I am trying to create a custom button to redirect to a different page where I'll create an Excel file for download. I'm just not sure how to set the `href`. I've tried this:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.export =
{
    className: 'buttons-alert',
    text: "Export All Test III",
    action: function (e, dt, node, config)
    {
        var SearchData = dt.rows({ filter: 'applied' }).data();
        var OrderData = dt.order();
        alert("Test Data for Searching: " + SearchData);
        alert("Test Data for Ordering: " + OrderData);
    },
    href: './AjaxHandler.php'
};
```

The `href` is ignored and not set. I need to set the `href`.

How do I do this?

I can see in the Dev Tools in Firefox that it has the property, but it is set to # like this:

[image]

**EDIT**

I have since tried setting the `href` after initialization like this:

```
$('.dt-button.buttons-alert').attr('href', './AjaxHandler.php');


document.querySelector('.buttons-alert').setAttribute('href', './AjaxHandler.php');
```

Neither one of these works, though, the `href` still shows only the #.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've gotten it to work, sort of. I am still not able to get the `href` set in the button. What I am able to do is this:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.export =
{
    className: 'buttons-alert',
    id: 'ExportButton',
    text: "Export All Test III",
    action: function (e, dt, node, config)
    {
        //This will send the page to the location specified
        window.location.href = './AjaxHandler.php';
    }
};
```

This accomplishes the same thing even though it does it a different way.

Comment: that was a lifesaving hack for me..
thanks buddy.
Also do let me know if you got into any bugs with this approach.

Comment: I just updated what I have working on my website. So far there haven't been any problems with it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I did to solve this issue. This puts my "Add record" button in the DataTable DOM

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
    ...,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>',
            className: 'btn btn-default btnAddJob',
            titleAttr: 'Add a new record',
            init: function (dt, node, config) {
                $(node).attr('href', 'put/your/href/here')
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: This do add href but it doesnot work on click

Answer (score 0):

dataTables doesn't have "href" in their options.
Buttons only have these options that can be used:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/#buttons

Comment: Yes, I've seen that page. Surely though since the `href` is there on the page there is a way to access it and set it to what I want?

Comment: You can always add href link dynamically with jquery after initializing the button.. $(".dt-button.buttons-alert").attr("href", "./AjaxHandler.php")

Comment: I tried this `$('dt-button.buttons-alert').attr('href', './AjaxHandler.php');` and it didn't make any difference, the `href` is still #

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to Mike's solution, as in his solution href is adding but link is not opening on click, so I slightly modified the code to make it work. Also, it would be helpful to some who is trying currently. Its an easy fix.

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
    ...,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>',
            className: 'btn btn-default btnAddJob',
            titleAttr: 'Add a new record',
            init: function (dt, node, config) {
                 $(node).click(function(){
                          
                    window.location.href = 'Your Link';
                          
                      })
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, so that the link opens in a new tab:

```
$("#my_table").DataTable({
    "buttons": [
        {
            text: 'Click me',
            action: function (e, dt, button, config) {
                window.open("https://example.com/path/page.html");
            }
        }
    ],
    "dom": 'Bfrtip', // https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom
    "info": false,
    // "language":
    'order': [[0, 'asc'],],
    "ordering": true,
    "paging": false,
    "searching": false,
});
```